# launch kdiff3 only during conflicts

Tags: mercurial, kdiff3

I configured mercurial to launch kdiff3 to resolve conflicts during merges. But not kdiff3 pops up every time I do merge, even when there are no conflicts.

Is there a way to configure mercurial to launch kdiff3 only when there are conflicts.

Here is my .hgrc

```
[ui]
username = ##### <#####@#####.com>

[extensions]
extdiff = 
fetch =

[extdiff]
cmd.kdiff3 = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3

[merge-tools]
kdiff3.executable = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
kdiff3.args = $base $local $other -o $output
kdiff3.priority = 1
```